# catching null exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

I'm working on a java application for android and I currently am getting a problem where the debugger is stepping into my catch block and somehow ex is null? Has anyone seen anything like this before?

```
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Debugger is coming through the catch block and ex is null ????
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the source code and the compiled classes are out of sync, so the debugger is stepping into the wrong block.

Try to do a clean and then a rebuild.

Comment: I cleaned the project and rebuilt, seems fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The exception will never be null in that block. If the instruction pointer in the debugger is pointing at the catch line, you need to step one more line to get the exception to be accessible to you. You may want to add a line of code (potentially a log call) to your catch block and put your break point on that to catch what ex is.

Comment: Yep, I even tried `throw null;` but then an instance `NullPointerException` is caught.

Comment: If you are saying I answered your question, then please click the checkbox next to my answer saying I solved your issue.

Comment: I was not the one who asked the question, so I cannot do that.

Comment: Sorry Ben.... didn't even realize you weren't the original poster. Must be out of my mind today.

Comment: No worries. I think your answer is correct though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add some log statements and check. Your `ex` may be out of scope.

Comment: David Carpenter in question says "// Debugger is coming through the catch block and ex is null ????". So "ex" is in scope.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem inside an AsyncTask, while debugging on a real device (Galaxy Tab 2). So I too can confirm, that this strange problem is real.

For me the accepted answer didn't help.

But in my case the problem mysteriously went away after unplugging the usb plug of the  device and connecting it again afterwards (and then running my app again).