# How is it possible that the Exception is null inside of a catch block?

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm curious how the following is possible.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I debug my code he jumps into the catch blog - so far so good - but than i check what kind of exception it is, and it is e = null?!

How is that even possible? I have an exception but the exception is null?

Greetings,

Comment: Check this : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755364/catching-null-exception>

Comment: For some reason, the debugger doesn't yet have the exception initialized before the first statement in the catch block. If you add a statement before, or if you step into and then out, it should be initialized.

Comment: Where is your debug pointer, when you check the value? if it is on the line `catch (Exception e) {`then your debugger has not caught the value of `e` yet. Go to the next line and check again.

Comment: And maybe your running debug session is out of sync with your current code. Try to clean and rebuild before running again

Comment: the debug pointer is in e.printstacktrace(); i tried to rebuild, still it does not work.

Comment: I'd say the class binary does not match your code, and you should rebuild.  Classloader thinks "catch (Exception e) {" is line 67, but your debugger thinks "e.printStackTrace();" is line 67;

Comment: You mean build - rebuild? I've already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is a problem with the debugger or the virtual machine - the exception is lazy loaded, that is, the exception is not loaded until needed. As long as no method from the exception is called, its data is not loaded. When the first method is called, the virtual machine *fills*  the exception fields.

You should see the exception after executing the `printStackTrace` or using the debugger to execute one method from that exception (e.g. Expression View in Eclipse).

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, any example what I should do there?

Comment: sorry, I only use Eclipse - but have seen something similar there: exception is __empty__ only after calling `printStackTrace` all fields are filled. What happens after executing the next line, I mean the `e.printStackTrace()`. Is it printed correctly? Can you see the exception in the debugger?

Comment: well, my debug pointer is at e.printStackTrace - or what do you mean?

Comment: what happens after executing that line (single step once)

Comment: It is the end of my code

Comment: normally the debuuger should stop after that line - but you can insert an additional (dummy) line, or just repeat the printStackTrace. Probably would be best to get help from someone using Android Studio.

Comment: oh wow, adding an additional e.printStackTrace in the line after the first e.printStackTrace shows me the exception.

Probably i don't have to understand this right? Well case and problem solved.